# How to typehint redux dispatcher with different return type than dispatch type?

Tags: typescript, redux

I want to typehint an action creator with a different type than the dispatch type.

I've tried to typehint the ThunkResult with both types but this is not ideal.

```js
// types.ts
interface AppListAction extends FetchAction {
  type: typeof APP_LIST,
  [FETCH]: {},
}

interface AppListSuccessAction extends FetchResponseAction {
  type: typeof APP_LIST_SUCCESS,
  response: Array<ListModel>
}

export type AppResponseActions =
  AppListSuccessAction

export type AppActions =
  AppListAction
  | AppResponseActions


// actions.ts
export const loadListCreator = (): AppActions => ({
  type: C_LIST,
  [FETCH]: {},
})

export const loadList = (): ThunkResult<AppResponseActions> => (dispatch: ThunkDispatcher) => dispatch(loadListCreator())
```

I expect no errors but instead I receive:

TypeScript error: Type 'AppActions' is not assignable to type 'AppResponseActions'.
  Type 'AppListAction' is not assignable to type 'AppResponseActions'.
    Property 'response' is missing in type 'AppListAction' but required in type 'AppListSuccessAction'.  TS2322

Answer (score 0):

To make your code compilable I made following assumptions

```
import { ThunkAction, ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';

const FETCH = 'fetch';

interface FetchAction {
    [FETCH]: object;
}

interface FetchResponseAction {
    prop2: string;
}

const APP_LIST = 'APP_LIST';
const APP_LIST_SUCCESS = 'APP_LIST_SUCCESS';

interface ListModel {
    prop3: string;
}
```

And after your code

```
type ThunkResult<R> = ThunkAction<R, State, undefined, AppActions>;
type ThunkDispatcher = ThunkDispatch<State, undefined, AppActions>;
```

Given assumptions above your code become compilable with following modification

```
export const loadList = (): ThunkResult<AppActions> => (dispatch: ThunkDispatcher) => dispatch(loadListCreator());
```

`ThunkResult<AppActions>` should have type for `R = AppActions`. `R` is return value from function of type `ThunkResult`. In Redux-Thunk source code [`ThunkAction`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/0e60b6264fb402afb328157c4337f5cc87a07b53/index.d.ts#L44) is defined as follows

```
export type ThunkAction<
    TReturnType,
    TState,
    TExtraThunkArg,
    TBasicAction extends Action
> = (
    dispatch: ThunkDispatch<TState, TExtraThunkArg, TBasicAction>,
    getState: () => TState,
    extraArgument: TExtraThunkArg
) => TReturnType;
```

So `ThunkAction` (on which `ThunkResult` is based) is a function which return value of type `TReturnType`.

Then you try to make `loadlist` of type `ThunkResult<>` equal to `(dispatch: ThunkDispatcher) => dispatch(loadListCreator())`. Essentially it is also function but returning result of `dispatch` call. `dispatch` is of type `ThunkDispatcher` and [from source](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/0e60b6264fb402afb328157c4337f5cc87a07b53/index.d.ts#L20) it has type

```
export interface ThunkDispatch<
    TState,
    TExtraThunkArg,
    TBasicAction extends Action
> {
    <TReturnType>(
        thunkAction: ThunkAction<TReturnType, TState, TExtraThunkArg, TBasicAction>
    ): TReturnType;
    <A extends TBasicAction>(action: A): A;
}
```

So it is overloaded function taking function with one agrument of type `A` and returning result of type `A`. As `dispatch` is called with result of `loadListCreator()` call which returns result of type `AppActions`, `A` is inferred to be `AppActions`.

Original code is correctly not compiled as you want to assign fucntion returning `AppActions` to function returning `AppResponseActions`. `AppActions` is union type and can be either `AppResponseActions` or `AppListAction`. In case it is `AppListAction` it cannot be assigned to `AppResponseActions`.

I think I've described clearly :-)

From practice point of view your code is a bit overcomplicated.

Consider simplifing it this way.

1. Inherit all actions from Action type

   ```
   import { Action } from 'redux';

   interface AppListAction extends Action {
       type: typeof APP_LIST,
       [FETCH]: {},
   }
   ```
2. Set type `ThunkResult` to following

   ```
   type ThunkResult = ThunkAction<void, State, undefined, AppActions>;
   ```

   Most probably you don't need `TReturnType`. Thunk actions just dispatch everything needed inside code and return nothing (`void`).
3. Action creators for sync actions may look like

   ```
   interface SyncAction1 extends Action {
       type: 'SYNC_ACTION',
       argument: string
   }

   const SomeSyncAction = (argument: string) => <SyncAction1>{ type: 'SYNC_ACTION', argument }
   ```
4. Action creators for async action may look like

   ```
   export const loadList = (): ThunkResult => (dispatch: ThunkDispatcher) => {
        dispatch(/* start loading */);
        const result = await // load api call
        dispatch(loadListCreator(result));
   }
   ```
5. Reducer will look like

   ```
   export function loadReducer (state = initalState, action: AppActions)
   // reducer code
   ```